# User Recommendation Email Body

Tags: php

The code below works great.  It allows a user to send emails to other people in order to recommend my site.

How can I replace "Michael" below with  $_POST['sendername']?  I tried and it didn't work.

Thanks in advance,

John

```
 $msg = "<html><body>Hello, your friend Michael recommends that you use <a href='http://www.site.com/'>site.com</a>  Please visit the site.<br><br><img src='http://site.com/images/blacklogo.PNG'></body></html>";
    $subject = "Try out Site.com";
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: ' . $_POST['sendername'] . "\r\n";
    foreach($_POST['email'] as $email){
    mail($email, $subject,$msg,$headers);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply:

```
 $msg = "<html><body> … ".htmlspecialchars($_POST['sendername'])." … </body></html>";
```

Comment: ...and just make sure you sanitize the input variables first. Don't take them straight from $_POST or you're just begging to be spam-hacked.

Comment: Gumbo, it works with double-quotes, ".htmlspecialchars($_POST['sendername'])."

I gave you credit.

Comment: @John: As the value of `$_POST['sendername']` is supposed to be used as the sender’s e-mail address, you should validate that value to be a valid e-mail address.

Comment: @John I normally include a script like that found at http://www.alt-php-faq.org/local/115/ at the top of all forms processing scripts. You also need to run all your $_POST variables through strip_tags, though there are more comprehensive sanitization methods - a Google search should see you right.

Comment: @da5id: I wouldn’t use that script. It will rather block fair people than spammers.